# ERROR - 2019-10-20 21:23:41 --> 404 Page Not Found: Login/index

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Quite new user to CodeIgniter here, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I recently tried to create login for with CI which should be accessible on sub.domain.com/login according to the guide I followed. However when I access the same I see the default CI "404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found." message.

In application/config/config.php I have changed the value for "$config['log_threshold']" to 4. The only message I am able to see in application/logs is the following:

```
INFO - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> Language Class Initialized
ERROR - 2019-10-20 21:31:15 --> 404 Page Not Found: Login/index
```

Could you please give more information how such errors are troubleshooted?